# React Typescript: How to dynamically add form elements with an onClick function for a Button element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to dynamically generate TextFields and then Store their values in an array in the state.

My imports:

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
```

I created a button below the TextField. I want to dynamically add TextFields after the button is clicked.

```
TextField required={true}
    onChange={e => this.state.book_authors.push(e.target.value)}
    className={this.props.classes.textField}
    label={"Author"}
    variant="outlined"
    type="text"/>

<Button
    variant="contained" color="primary"
    action={() => this.handleAddAuthorField()}
    className={this.props.classes.button}
>
    Add Author
</Button>
```

My method:

```
 handleAddAuthorField(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <Row>
            <TextField
                required={true}
                onChange={e => this.state.book_authors.push(e.target.value)}
                className={this.props.classes.textField}
                label={"Author"}
                variant="outlined"
                type="text"
            />
        </Row>

    )

}
```

The state, book_authors is to store the TextField inputs as an array.

```
public state: IsBookState = {
    book_authors: [],
};
```

After I clicked the button the TextField didn't genereate.

Answer (score 0):

There's several things here that are a bit off, but lets focus on the question. I feel like I'm missing some code, I'm not seeing where the text field is meant to be rendered.

You'd want something like the following:

```
this.state = { authors: [] } // Set in constructor

render() {
    const { authors } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
            {authors.map(author => (
                <TextField author={author} />
            )}
            <Button onClick={this.handleAddAuthorField}>Add author field</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This code is very abridged, but my point is that you need to render your components somewhere - and like I said I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking, please clarify what exactly is the intended functionality.

Comment: What is meant by author={author} in TextField?

Comment: It sets a prop called "author" in the TextField component, which will be the current element of the "authors" array when we loop through it with map. So to display data in the component you could for instance do `<div>{this.props.author.name}</div>` assuming each element of the array we're mapping has a "name" attribute. @MuizUvais